# Xperia Z3 [ Android Nougat ] not being recognise by Android Studio

Tags: android, sony-xperia, android-7.0-nougat

I recently updated my Xperia Z3 to the new Android Nougat Developer. However when trying to debug my Android App from Android Studio to my phone, the AVD says  "No device install'.

I even check the adb which also states that no device can be found. I try everything from removing the phone from USB and adding again, restarting the IDE, restarting the phone.....

So how can I fix this???

Comment: Did you try going to Settings->Developer Options and enabling USB debugging?

Comment: Yep did that, activated developer settings, there was one thing thou, the device manager states it couldn't find the device driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Click this link to get the driver. It should solve the issue](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-z3-driver/)

*Once the driver is installed you need to **authenticate your pc** to be used for development purpose via auth keys which will appear on your phone screen once you connect it after installing pc drivers.*

Comment: Hi Kamal, just need a little bit guidance, how would I go about installing it. I attempted this technique from this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver. However it still wouldn't be recognised from Windows

Comment: @ShaidK Hey, You need to install google usb driver from you sdk manager. Open stand alone sdk manager and scroll down til you see GOOGLE USB   Driver. **You will find this under EXTRAS in your stand alone sdk manager** Do that and see if it works now. And do remember to install sony driver too.

Comment: Got it to work, Just for other who have same problems, look at this link: http://www.beritahuaja.com/2015/11/how-to-install-sony-usb-driver-manually.html?en-gb. Install it as it shows, then relate your device as it show it. Thank Kamal for your help :)

Comment: Glad I could be of some help :) . Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Sony PC Companion. This should install all of the necessary drivers for communication with adb: [xperia-companion](http://support.sonymobile.com/global-en/tools/xperia-companion/)

Comment: Hi Singh, main problem is that once you update to Nougat Developer your device will not be recognised by the Xperia Companion (I recall reading it on the Sony Care)